# Office 365 exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, shared-mailbox

I have the following scenario:
8 email addresses (3 services & 5 people):

- info@example.com
- sales@example.com
- accounting@example.com
- user1@example.com
- user2@example.com
- user3@example.com
- user4@example.com
- user5@example.com

I need all the users to be able to receive and reply as services but also keep their own version of the mailbox...
so for example when an email is sent to info I want all five of them to receive it and be able to reply as info (and the sent email must be viewable by all) but if someone deletes an email or creates folders inside his mailbox the mailbox of the other users will not be affected...
I have full licenses for all the email addresses so I can make them normal, shared or what ever mailbox options exchange 365 provides...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ideally the users should be able to see there mailboxes from multiple devices via software (Outlook etc) or webmail.

The current setup is : Exchange connection for the user1, user2 emails and POP for the services but the administration overhead and the limitations of POP are starting to cause problems (for example we are not able to restore deleted items from the POP accounts).

Comment: Sounds like you need a combination of Exchange and POP3 accounts

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
This is what I am currently using but it is very complex to manage.
I have setup the user1 user2 etc as exchange and the services as pop but if a user uses more than one device the mails are received multiple times (due to POP). and also I am not able to use the features of exchange (such as restore deleted mails, contacts etc) since I am connecting with POP...

Comment: @Dave Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question.

Comment: With your specific conditions, I don't know of any way this could simplified... If they could use a common directory structure it would be pretty easy.

Comment: @acejavelin True.. I was planning to set them up with shared mailbox for the services and define as one of the users as "editor" that would be able to manage the shared mailbox. But unfortunately each user needs a copy... I was thinking of creating a normal mailbox for the services and put an auto-forward rule that sends any new mails to the users. and then somehow allow the users to send us the services maybe via (POP) but do not allow the POP to download any mails... how does that sound?

Comment: and to answer my own question ... then they will have access via outlook.com to all incoming mails but will not able to respond as the service..? am I correct? is there some kind of send us feature in exchange without actually connecting to the mailbox?